# How to get text from iframe of Dialogflow Web Demo

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to extract the server-response text from the in iframe of Dialog Web Demo

Here's my code- Currently, the output is `null`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en\">
<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial- scale=1, user-scalable=no\"/>
<title>Dialog</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<iframe
    id="dialog"
    allow="microphone;"
    width="350"
    height="430"
    src="https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">  
</iframe>
</div>
<div align="center">
<script>
     var dialogFrame = document.getElementById("dialog");
     var dialogDocument = dialogFrame.contentWindow.document;
     var dialogResponse = dialogDocument.getElementById("server-response");
     document.write(dialogResponse);
</script>
</div>
</body>
</hmtl>
```

I'm expecting to extract text responded by Dialogflow, but the result is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Data cannot be retrieved from the HTML `<iframe>` element, which is only a display block. Data can be retrieved through API call; in Dialogflow, you get this data with [Fulfillments](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment).

Check below flow to deploy a Node app on App Engine, serving a Dialogflow Chat at the default endpoint, and posting fulfillment data at `/fulfillment` endpoint.

A) [Configure fulfillment](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/configure)

Pay attention to the following:

- URL: input your HTTPS Express POST endpoint (e.g. https://[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com/fulfillment)
- leave all other fields blank
- Domains: Enable webhook for all domains
- Once created and saved, you still need to enable fulfillment for each Intent (and their follow-up if any) that you are using

B) Application

- Create a Node App in App Engine from the console

Then deploy this app, replacing the `<iframe>` with yours:

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs8
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.5.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

function WebhookProcessing(req, res) {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({request: req, response: res});

    console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
    console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.queryResult.queryText));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.queryResult.fulfillmentText));

}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));

});

app.post('/fulfillment', function (req, res) {
    WebhookProcessing(req, res);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en\">
<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial- scale=1, user-scalable=no\"/>
<title>Dialog</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <iframe
                allow="microphone;"
                width="350"
                height="430"
                src="https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">  
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</hmtl>
```

When user starts a conversation in the chat, the function `WebhookProcessing` outputs the logs of the body and header of each request (each message sent by user), and extracts and logs the values of both fields `queryText` (user's message) and `fulfillmentText` (Bot's reply).

Note that this is just an example of integration in App Engine, you could also consider deploying a Cloud Function, and if you work with a Firebase database, then you can [use the inline editor and deploy the function from Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/configure#create_a_webhook_with_the_inline_editor).